# positive invertible maps which are not *-automorphisms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra. Is there a unital positive self-map $F:A\to A$ which is invertible (i.e. injective and surjective) but not a $*$-automorphism? If yes, how does appear its Gelfand-Naimark-Segal covariant representation associated to a state $\varphi$ on $A$ which is invariant under $F$? Are there examples of such maps which are involutive (i.e. such that $F^2=id_A$, or equivalently $F=F^{-1}$?

Comment: There are many unital positive bijection of the form $a\mapsto S^*aS+(1-S^*S)\varphi(a)$, where $S$ invertible and contractive. However, if you are asking unital positive $F$ with positive inverse, then $F$ is a Jordan isomorphism.

Comment: Many thanks, I wanted also to exclude anti-automorphisms. It seems to me that, for such maps, the GNS covariant representation doesn't exist in general

Comment: It is inconsiderate to cross-post without indicating so: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4870592/invertible-positive-maps-which-are-not-automorphisms